# Lee's proof of the rank theorem for abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, free-groups

I am going through Prof. Lee's "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" second time through, trying to do all the exercises and problems. My question is about a proof of the rank theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. If it is trivial or silly, I will gladly delete it. I just want to go through the book carefully, dotting the i's and crossing the t's.

Suppose $f:G\to H$ is a surjective homomorphism of abelian groups. Assume that $G$ is finitely generated and let $K=\ker f$.  Then $\text{rank}\ G= \text{rank}\ K+ \text{rank}\ H.$

Recall that the rank of an abelian group $G$ is defined by $\text{rank}\ G:=\text{rank}\ G/G_{tor}.$

One has the homomorphism $\tilde f:G/G_{tor}\to H/H_{tor}$ defined in the obvious way.

Now, Lee states "clearly the kernel of $\tilde f$ contains $K/K\cap G_{tor}".$ I don't understand what is meant by this. How are $\ker \tilde f$ and elements of $K/K\cap G_{tor}$ comparable? Or are we considering $\tilde f$ "restricted" to the latter set?

I think I can do the proof in a different way. A sketch:

If we consider the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \ker \tilde f\xrightarrow{\tilde i} G/G_{tor}\xrightarrow{\tilde f} H/H_{tor}\rightarrow 0$,  since each of these groups is free abelian, the sequence can be written $0\to \mathbb{Z}^{n}\to \mathbb{Z}^{m}\to \mathbb{Z}^{l}\to 0$ from which it follows that $\mathbb{Z}^{m}\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{n}\oplus \mathbb{Z}^{l}$ because the sequence splits. The result follows from this.

But of course, this is not the way Lee does the proof.

edit: $\ker \tilde f$ is certainly free abelian, but as pointed out in the answer, relating it to $K$ itself is just Lee's approach.

Comment: I know that subgroups of free abelian groups are free abelian. This is Lee's prop 9.19.

Comment: Yes; that's not really the problem, though, which is why I deleted. The problem is that now you don't get that it has rank $\mathrm{rank} K$ until you connect it to $K$.

Comment: Right. This is what Lee does and  I realized this upon sitting down to finish the proof for myself. Thanks for clearing this up, Your answer settled it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is $\tilde{f}$ defined? You have the map $f\colon G\to H$, and you have the map $\pi\colon H\to H/H_{\mathrm{tor}}$. Since $f(G_{\mathrm{tor}})\subseteq H_{\mathrm{tor}}$, the kernel of $\pi\circ f$ contains $G_{\mathrm{tor}}$, so it factors through $G/G_{\mathrm{tor}}$; this is the map $\tilde{f}$.

What is the kernel of $\pi\circ f$? It contains $K$, and it contains $G_{\mathrm{tor}}$. Therefore, it contains $KG_{\mathrm{tor}}$. Thus, the kernel of $\tilde{f}$ contains $KG_{\mathrm{tor}}/G_{\mathrm{tor}}$.

By the Second (or Third, depending how you number them) Isomorphism Theorem,
$$\frac{KG_{\mathrm{tor}}}{G_{\mathrm{tor}}} \cong \frac{K}{K\cap G_{\mathrm{tor}}}.$$

So Lee is abusing language a bit by saying the kernel "contains" $K/K\cap G_{\mathrm{tor}}$. It actually contains the canonically isomorphic group $KG_{\mathrm{tor}}/G_{\mathrm{tor}}$.

---

Your proposed path does not work. You say that the short exact sequence
$$1\to K\to G\to H\to 1$$
induces a short exact sequence
$$1 \to \frac{K}{K_{\mathrm{tor}}} \to \frac{G}{G_{\mathrm{tor}}} \to \frac{H}{H_{\mathrm{tor}}} \to 1.$$
But that sequence need not be exact: consider the case of $K=2\mathbb{Z}$, $G=\mathbb{Z}$, and $H=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. The sequence you get by moding out by the torsion is
$$1 \to 2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\to 1\to 1,$$
with the first map the canonical inclusion. But this map is not surjective, which is what you would need for this sequence to be exact.

The problem is that while $G_{\mathrm{tor}}$ certainly maps to $H_{\mathrm{tor}}$, it need not be the *only* thing that maps to $H_{\mathrm{tor}}$: you can have nontorsion elements of $G$ become torsion in the quotient.

Comment: If we consider $0\rightarrow \ker \tilde f\xrightarrow{\tilde i} G/G_{tor}\xrightarrow{\tilde f} H/H_{tor}\rightarrow 0$, I think it works now.

Comment: @Matematleta Well, that will certainly be exact, but the problem is that now you need to relate $\ker\tilde{f}$ to $K$ somehow... because you don't know that $\ker\tilde{f}$ is free abelian, like you did with $K/K_{\mathrm{tor}}$. And trying to relate it to $K$ will almost certainly just lead you to what Lee is doing in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I am finding this out now as I try to work it out!  Thank you for your answer, very clear, and for taking the time to comment.

Comment: @Matematleta: Okay, proving it is free abelian isn't hard. But you still need to connect it to $K$, so you'll just end up back in Lee's argument, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Once one knows that every fin. gen. abelian group is a direct sum of torsion and free, then it is clear why this result must hold. The sequence decomposes as a direct sum of two sequences. The first has $H$ torsion, so rank $G$ equals rank $K$. The second has $H$ free and $K=0$, so $G=H$ and they have the same rank.